# custom font not importing

Tags: html, css, xampp, font-face

none of the font CSS import seems to work...
I thought maybe it was because I wasn't using xampp, but it doesn't seem to matter... still doesn't work, I don't understand.

```
<style>
@font-face{
    font-family: "ogrejuice";
    src: url('ogrejuice.ttf'),
    url('ogrejuice.eot'); /* IE */
}
</style>
```

attempt 2

```
<style>
@font-face{
    <!-- font-family: "ogrejuice"; -->
    src: url('ogrejuice.woff2'),
    src: local('ogrejuice.woff2'), 
    <!-- url('ogrejuice.eot'); /* IE */ -->
}
</style>
```

attempt 3

```
<style>
@font-face{
    <!-- font-family: "ogrejuice"; -->
    src: url('ogrejuice.woff2'),
    src: local('ogrejuice.woff2'), 
    <!-- url('ogrejuice.eot'); /* IE */ -->
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "ogrejuice";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: block;
  src: url("../ogrejuice.eot");
  src: url("../ogrejuice.eot?#iefix") format("ie9-skip-eot"),
  url("../ogrejuice.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("..ogrejuice.woff") format("woff");
}
</style>
```

attempt 4

```
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(ogrejuice.woff);
}
</style>
```

Comment: What does the devtools (Network) tells you about fonts being loaded or not found?

Comment: I don't have any errors in firefox console. I just use firefox and notepad++

Answer (score 0):

ok so. For all first time custom font users out there... when you set the font.. That doesn't mean your page will use it... Consider the fallowing

```
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(aesymatt.ttf);
}
body{
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
</style>
```

The above code works fine for me. Somehow, setting the font-face doesn't actually do anything except make the font available, I guess? Definitely would not have thought of that. I don't normally use the @ symbol in the CSS of my projects except for specific cases like break points, so I haven't paid any attention to it until now.

Comment: _I don't see how `@` symbol is relevant here ;)_ So basically you thought that adding a font would make it default?

Comment: Absolutely! didn't even give it a second thought  :)